# Div on my site has 100% width but is not as wide as the body?

Tags: html, css

My site has a div that scrolls up the page. It fills 100% of the screen, but for some reason there is a slight bit of horizontal scroll available and the background extends that extra bit.

I am attempting to get the div to match the width of the screen/background without any horizontal scrolling available. It is on the far right that the issue takes place.

[image]

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="summaryPanel">
        <p>Summary</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(../images/trees.jpeg);
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    z-index: -2;
}

.summaryPanel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10vh;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;     // I also tried "100%"
    background-color: #242A31;
    border-top: 3px solid rgb(74, 74, 74);
}
```

Comment: Can I see your site live?

Comment: hey can you add `overflow-x:hidden` as looks like your site is more of scrolling vertically

Comment: Add the `overflow-x: hidden` to the body selector?

Comment: I'll push my site live to watsoncn.info

Comment: i checked 'watsoncn.info' could not find any issue with scrolling in my pc

Comment: Just pushed the new content to the site!

Comment: what browser and screen resolution of yours.

Comment: I've tried Chrome and Safari on both 2560 x 1600 and 1920 x 1080 displays. Identical results.

Answer (score 3):

You should try like this. Add a new class (`wrapper`) in place of `body`

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0}
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url(../images/trees.jpeg);
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    z-index: -2;
}
.summaryPanel {
    position: relative;
    top: 10vh;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #242A31;
    border-top: 3px solid rgb(74, 74, 74);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="summaryPanel">
        <p>Summary</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".summaryPanel").height($(window).height());
$(".summaryPanel").width($(window).width());
});
```

use jQuery to set the width and height of the div

Comment: This is absolutely unnecessary. Why use a heavy handed jQuery approach when CSS can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

Add to body tag

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but I think this will solve your problem...

```
 body 
       {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          width:100%;//if needed
          height:100%;//if needed
       }
       #divID
       {
         margin: 0;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%
         background-color: red;//for test
       }
```

100% is 100% of its parent, More Info  [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-width)